# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

Since upgrading to 3.1, I seemed to have lost my routing. My endpoints are now just returning a 404 and I have ran out of ideas of what the issue could be. Can anyone see if I'm doing something stupid in my below setup code? All that really changed in my setup code was that I stopped using

```
app.UseMvc
```

And now use the endpoint instead

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Code below

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/guild")]
public class GuildController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("create")]        
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]CreateGuildRequest request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        var domain = Configuration["Auth0:Domain"];

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = domain;
            options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
        });
        
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) 
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .Build());
        });
        
        services.AddControllers();
        
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "clientapp/dist"; });
        
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "clientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port: 8080);
            }
        });
        
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware order matters. Place your `UseSpa()` after `UseEndpoints()`

```cs
// this should be the last two middlewares, in this order
           
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "clientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port: 8080);
    }
});
```